PowerBi service pipeline/Error :deserializing source JSON file
can somebody help me please with the following error, which I encounter while trying to preview my data in powerbi service pipeline:
error JSON format
My source is a REST type and unlike HTTP type, REST type doesn't propose to choose a file format "JSON" in powerbi service.
My SOURCE and DESTINATION connections are ok, which is surprising is that my destination preview data is visible.
Thank you a lot for you help.
I tried to use HTTP instead of REST but token is required for Salesforce connection. even though HTTP Salesforce connection is ok, I don't think it's valid at the end because the token cannot be registered here. I am new to it, so don't know lots of things.
